# Where to go go-karting in Hong Kong?

Tags: activities, hong-kong

I know the main track was closed after a lethal freak accident.

I don't need anything big though. It's just been my dream to go go-karting.

Are there any options, and what are the prices?

Comment: It might help if you indicated what the 'main track' is, so people don't just answer with one that might be closed :/

Comment: It was called Diamond Coast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are none left after the ones in Kai Tak and Diamond Coast closed in Kong Kong. you will have to go to China or Macao.

In [Macao](http://www.kartingasia.com/kart_tracks/kartodromo-de-macau-china--t109.html) there is one the Cotai strip behind the golf court. I have however never been there and could not find an email/website either.

There are two in Zuhai: The [Zhuhai Golden Apple Karting Circuit](http://www.kartingasia.com/kart_tracks/golden-apple-karting-club-t272.html) (used by the HK GoCart club) and a kart track on the [Main Circuit in Zuhai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhuhai_International_Circuit), with their own [racing club](http://www.sunnyracing.com/big/main.asp?id=21).

You might want to ask the HK club for further info: http://www.hkkartclub.org/

Chances are however, that you will not get very far with English on either of them.

Answer (score 3):

I just found this 深圳极速赛车场

https://goo.gl/maps/i8mMLst5Ekm

It a bit far tho. But I was told a taxi ride from the border is about 100-200buk hkd? It seem they even have rental for 100cc Yamaha gokart (the fast kind). Will be going there and giving it a try sometime next month.

edit: it is confirmed. they have both 80cc (90 china yan) and 100cc (200 china yan) go kart to rent. Taxi from border is about 120 china yan to 200 china yan depending on which border you cross. just go to google map and put in 深圳极速赛车场. I posted some photo of how it looks on google map.